# Identify IdP from SAML and OIDC configurations

Tags: openid-connect, saml, saml-2.0, identity, idp

User has configured our app to connect to any identity provider using SAML or OpenID Connect protocol. From the configuration is there a way to identity what is the source Identity provider be it Azure AD, Google Cloud Identity, Okta, PingIdentity among others?

for oidc I tried to check the .well-known/openid-configuration but the domain of all the endpoints is the custom domain of enterprise rather than IdP

Comment: I would check cookies for their names and associated products.

Answer (score 0):

No. There are "hints" that might be derived from path patterns, but that's not definitive - at all. Especially since a reverse proxy could be involved.